# Problems uploading schema in cassandra

Tags: java, schema, nosql, cassandra, jmx

I am setting up a single node install of Cassandra on my Ubuntu VM. I modified the cassandra.yaml file under /cassandra/conf with my own custom schema. When I tried using the schematool utility under /cassandra/bin, I got the error:

> Cannot import schema when one already
>   exists

When I tried navigating to the MBEAN loadSchemaFromYAML from the JMX console:

> Problem invoking loadSchemaFromYAML:
>   java.rmi.unmarshalexception:Error
>   Unmarshalling return;nested exception
>   is:
>   Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.cassandra.config.ConfigurationException(no
>   security manager:RMI class loader
>   disabled)

Can somebody point out what is going on over here and how do I get my schema loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only import the schema from cassandra.yaml one time.  (This is now deprecated, by the way.)  If you want to import the schema from cassandra.yaml again, you'll need to wipe out your data directories (/var/lib/cassandra/*) and restart Cassandra.

Your other option (and what you will need to do in the future) is create the keyspaces and column families using bin/cassandra-cli or another client.

Here's an [article on live schema modifications](http://www.riptano.com/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-live-schema-updates) to get you started.

Comment: Based on the link you have provided, it does seem like if we introduced a newer version of the cassandra.yaml and restarted the server, the schema definitions will be picked up. Is there a reason why the schema import facility via cassandra.yaml was deprecated? Being a j2ee rookie, I was also wondering why the jmx console threw the exception that I described.

Comment: No, the new schema will definitely not get picked up on restart unless you wipe the existing data and re-import.  It's deprecated because having multiple sources of "truth" regarding the schema causes problems, and live schema modifications are a much better option (for clustering reasons).  I'm not a J2EE/JMX guy either, and I'm not really sure why that particular exception is being thrown :/ . I don't think that's the normal one.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the multiple sources of "truth" regarding the schema?

Comment: Well, if you accept modifications to the schema through a configuration file and you also accept those modifications through an API, quirky scenarios need to be handled, especially if the schema does not have to be "imported" from the configuration file. It simplifies the code path greatly to pick one or the other.